# increase item max size in memcached?

Tags: memcached

i am using memcached on my centos server , my project is large and has objects more than 1MB which i need to save to memcached , well , i can't ! because the max_item_size is 1MB , anyway to edit that ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cache over 1mb memcache alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977676/cache-over-1mb-memcache-alternatives)

Comment: check out how to do this in Ruby on Rails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352553/how-to-increase-memcache-slab-size-above-1mb-with-dalli-and-rails/37485215#37485215

Comment: Also sometimes memcached client sets it's own max size limitation. For example, with Python's `memcached` this may be needed in addition to -I 15m: `import memcache ; client=memcache.Client([('localhost',11211)], server_max_value_length=15 * 1024 * 1024)`

Comment: Here is another answer on the same - https://stackoverflow.com/q/1440722/6563567

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can change the limit quickly by edit the configuration file [/etc/memcached.conf] adding:

```
# Increase limit 
-I 128M
```

Or if you have trouble with SO config run it with command line directly

```
memcached -I 128M
```

Comment: Is there a way to configure this size in Tomcat context.xml when configuring memcahed SessionManager?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Memcache >= 1.4.2, this is now configurable.  Here is an example of how to set this in your init script for starting Memcache on CentOS: http://www.alphadevx.com/a/387-Changing-the-maximum-item-size-allowed-by-Memcache

Answer (score 3):

You can compile memcached and change the memory allocation setting to use POWER_BLOCK's, in the slabs.c file (or you can recompile and user malloc/free, but that is the greater of the evils).

http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_items_limited_to_1_megabyte_in_size?

I would seriously consider what you are caching and how it can be more modular, > 1MB in active memory is large.

Comment: i will be using 5 blocks of 2 MB each only ;) thants all what i need thanks :)

Comment: As of memcache 1.4.2, this is now a configurable parameter at startup.  See "Configurable maximum item size" in http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/ReleaseNotes142

Comment: Original link in solution is obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

Spent tons of time to figure this out:
in `/etc/sysconfig/memcached` edit options

```
OPTIONS="-l 127.0.0.1 -I 3m"
```

then `systemctl restart memcached` to take effect.

Would recommend option `-l 127.0.0.1` it secures to localhost usage only and `-I 3m` increases the limit as described above.

With Centos 7 I had no luck with these paths */etc/memcached.conf* */etc/default/memcached*